# SQL, Hibernate - get all new rows from specified ID

Tags: java, mysql, sql, hibernate

I have table like this:

```
id (int)    name (varchar)
--------    --------------
1           abc
2           def
3           ghi
4           jkl
5           mno
```

I need to write method in dao for get all new rows from specified ID.

```
public List<Test> findTestFromId(int id) {      
        return this.sessionFactory.getCurrentSession()
                .createQuery("FROM Test t WHERE ???????????")
                .setInteger("id", id).list();
}
```

So if I call `findTestFromId(3)` I want to get List with rows 4 and 5 (or 3,4,5)...

Can you please help me with query?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about following:

```
public List<Test> findTestFromId(int id) {      
    return this.sessionFactory.getCurrentSession()
            .createQuery("FROM Test t WHERE id > :id")
            .setInteger("id", id).list();
}
```

This should help you.